# Save the Tab state during orientation change

Tags: android

I have 2 tabs , for example Tab1 & Tab2 which is displayed on the screen. Let the tabs be displayed on the PORTRAIT orientation.

Tab1 displays Activity1 & Tab2 displays Activity2.

Currently , the selected tab state is Tab2 . Now , I change the orientation for PORTRAIT to LANDSCAPE . On changing the orientation to LANDSCAPE mode , instead of displaying Tab2 , currently Tab1 is displayed.

Basically , I want to save the Tab state when there is orientation change.

In order to perform the objective of saving the tab state , I am writing the following code:

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveCurrentTabState(getSelectedTab());
}

private void saveCurrentTabState(int value) {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putInt(
            "tabState", value).commit();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setCurrentTab(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .getInt("tabState", 0));

}
```

I wanted to know , is my approach correct or not & whether the above code is a proper way of saving the tab state on changing the orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the best way. You should use onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() and getLastNonConfigurationInstance() to retain the state between config changes. Those methods are specifically for saving state during config changes.

```
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
}

public void onCreate() {
   ...
   Integer lastTab = (Integer) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
   if(lastTab != null) {
      mTabHost.setCurrentTab(lastTab);
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Robby for your reply . Can you kindly elaborate/provide details on the lastTab parameter & the method setActiveTab(lastTab) ?

Answer (score 18):

That's not the way it should be done... instead use the:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("tabState", getSelectedTab());
}
```

Then, on the `onCreate` method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle state){
     // do the normal onCreate stuff here... then:
     if( state != null ){
         setCurrentTab(state.getInt("tabState"));
     }
}
```

The Robby's solution will work too and involves using the `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` method. I actually like and prefer that method over `onSaveInstanceState` since it allows you save a complex object that represents the state of the app, not only parceables inside a `Bundle`.

So when to use one of the other? It depends on the data you need to save/restore the state of the app. For simple things like saving the tab state, it's almost the same.

Comment: you can also get position with `mActionBar.getSelectedTab().getPosition()` and set with `mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(int)`

Comment: ActionBar did not exist when this question was asked/answered; also, he is using `TabHost` class.

Comment: @Dori +1 for your comment, it was useful for me, as we have 2013 now and many people are using the action bar with navigation tabs :)