# How to save tab state during orientation in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have 2 tabs , for example Tab1 & Tab2 which is displayed on the screen. Let the tabs be displayed on the PORTRAIT orientation.

Tab1 displays Activity1 & Tab2 displays Activity2.

Currently , the selected tab state is Tab2 . Now , I change the orientation for PORTRAIT to LANDSCAPE . On changing the orientation to LANDSCAPE mode , instead of displaying Tab2 , currently Tab1 is displayed.

My code:

```
public class TabBarExample extends TabActivity {

    TabHost tabHost;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab);

        /* TabHost will have Tabs */
        tabHost= (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
        TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");


        firstTabSpec.setIndicator("First Tab Name").setContent(new Intent(this,FirstTab.class));
        secondTabSpec.setIndicator("Second Tab Name").setContent(new Intent(this,SecondTab.class));


        tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
        tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);



        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height =40;
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height =40;

        for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)  
        {  
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A4117"));  
        }  

        Integer lastTab = (Integer) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        if(lastTab != null) {
           tabHost.setCurrentTab(lastTab);
        } 
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C35817"));  
    } 
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)  
        {  
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A4117"));  
        }  

        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C35817"));  


    }
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        return tabHost.getCurrentTab();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317660/save-the-tab-state-during-orientation-change).

You have to play with `SaveInstanceState` and `RestoreInstanceState`.

See this [Example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3801/how-to-use-saved-instance-state-and-restore-instance-state-with-spinners-in-andr).

[To know more Read this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)